# Understanding how jQuery works internally

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to understand how `jQuery` works internally. `jQuery` exposes a global `$` variable, which can be used like:

```
$('.abc') // returns a list of DOM nodes having class abc
$.ajax() // used to perform AJAX requests
```

As you can see, `$` is a function, from statement 1, while it's an object, from statement 2. Now I know that this is possible because of `function Objects` in JavaScript, meaning that a function is also an `Object` in JavaScript, and hence you can attach methods to it. But I am not sure how this is achieved internally?

I was looking at [this](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-create-your-own-vanilla-js-dom-manipulation-library-like-jquery/) blog post which explains how the 'constructor pattern' can be used to mimic jQuery, but how would you attach methods on `$` using that pattern? Or does jQuery use some completely different pattern? Here is a small implementation of jQuery from that. This code can do `$(selector)`, but how do I add `$.method` in it?

```js
// Mini jQuery implementation 
var $ = (function() {
  var JQuery = function(selector) {
    if (selector === "document") {
      this.elements = [document];
    } else if (selector === "window") {
      this.elements = [window];
    } else {
      this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
    return this;
  };

  JQuery.prototype.each = function(callback) {
    this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
      callback(element);
    });
    return this;
  };

  JQuery.prototype.addClass = function() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return this;
    else {
      this.each(element => {
        element.classList.add(...arguments);
      });
      return this;
    }
  };

  return function(selector) {
    return new JQuery(selector);
  };
})();

// Use our mini jQuery to turn background of matching Nodes green
$(".abc").addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.abc {
  background : red;
}

.abc.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="abc">Node 1</div>
  <div class="abc">Node 2</div>
```

Comment: Have you check https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js ?

Comment: @ariel Yes I did, but I don't see method like `ajax` defined there, which are available directly on `$`.

Comment: Ajax is here, its added with the `extend` method. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js

Comment: In javascript, everything is an object. Functions are objects, and objects have properties (which can be any object, including functions!)

Comment: @darKnight I've created this github repo [how-jQuery-works](https://github.com/AmraniCh/how-jQuery-works) especially for learning how jQuery works internally.

Comment: @darKnight if you find my answer blow useful please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor pattern actually does not solve the problem of `$.method`, if you want to achieve the `$.method` you have to work around a little bit, this is a simple solution based on your example :

```js
var $ = (function() {
  
  var JQuery = function(selector) {
    if (selector === "document") {
      this.elements = [document];
    } else if (selector === "window") {
      this.elements = [window];
    } else {
      this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
    return this;
  };

  JQuery.prototype.each = function(callback) {
    this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
      callback(element);
    });
    return this;
  };

  JQuery.prototype.addClass = function() {
    if (arguments.length === 0) return this;
    else {
      this.each(element => {
        element.classList.add(...arguments);
      });
      return this;
    }
  };

  return function(selector) {
    
    // A simple function for extending object properties/values to another object
    $.extend = JQuery.prototype.extend = function(source) {
      if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'object') return;

      for (var prop in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          this[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    };
    
    // Extend all the JQuery prototype methods to the '$' object
    $.extend(JQuery.prototype);
    
    // Others extensions that's can only accessed via '$.method' and not '$('selector').method'
    $.extend({
      ajax: function() {},
      noop: function() {},
    });
    
    return new JQuery(selector);
  };
})();

// Use our mini jQuery to turn background of matching Nodes green
$("body").addClass("highlight");
$.addClass.call($('body'), 'selected');
```

jQuery doesn't use the constructor pattern for the `$` or `jQuery` objects, if you check [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a503c691dc06c59acdafef6e54eca2613c6e4032/src/core.js#L22) you can see that's the `$` or `jQuery` is just a *constructor function* of the init function `jQuery.fn.init` defined [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a503c691dc06c59acdafef6e54eca2613c6e4032/src/core/init.js#L17), all the initialized jQuery object `$("body")` methods are attached to the `jQuery.fn` (alias for `jQuery.prototype`) (this is one example [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a503c691dc06c59acdafef6e54eca2613c6e4032/src/attributes/attr.js#L21)), the other methods like `ajax`, `noop`, `isReady` are attached directly to the `$` object (example of ajax method [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a503c691dc06c59acdafef6e54eca2613c6e4032/src/ajax.js#L383)). that's why we can access those methods with `$.method` syntax.

Sorry for my bad English, I hope this makes sense to you.

**Edit1:** For anyone who's interested in how jQuery works internally and want to know more about jQuery core, I've created this github repo [how-jQuery-work](https://github.com/AmraniCh/how-jQuery-works) especially for this purpose. Thanks!